# Validate array object in laravel form request validation?

Tags: php, json, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am sending following json array to server,

```
 {
    "details": {
        "0": {
            "name": "agency name"
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "agency name arabic"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to validate details in form request.

I tried as follows but not working fine,

```
protected $rules = [
        'details.*.name' => 'required|string',
    ];
```

Comment: What data set failed to validate? The one in your question is acceptable by the rules you've specified.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you don't send array here, you should send it like this:

```
{
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "agency name"
        },
        {
            "name": "agency name arabic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I send below array from a HTML+Vue.js data grid/table:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [item_id] => 1
        [item_no] => 3123
        [size] => 3e
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [item_id] => 2
        [item_no] => 7688
        [size] => 5b
    )
```

And use this to validate:

```
$this->validate($request, [ '*.item_id' => 'required|integer', '*.item_no' => 'required|integer', '*.size' => 'required|max:191', ]);
```